# Sort array based on property existance

Tags: swift

I have an array of chats and I want to sort them based on existence of messages inside them. It is possible that chat has no messages, and messages are optional.

I can't wrap my head around this or how to approach this. I have been trying to find some good sorting code here but failed.

```
chats.sort {
     guard let first = $0.messages, let second = $1.messages else { return false }
     return first && !second
}
```

Error: `Cannot convert value of type '[Message]' to expected argument type 'Bool'`

Whatever I try in `sort`method ends with some kind of error. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the sort based on whether `messages` is `nil` or not.

```
chats.sort { return $0.messages != nil && $1.messages == nil }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your result `messages` is not a `Bool` instance.

You try to say:

> [Message] and not [Message]

Swift doesn't understand you.

Probable you try to check the 'messages' parameter in obj-c style (or not). Swift doesn't allow to check nil value using implicit conversion.

one of the possible solutions:
1. If you try to use a wrong parameter

```
chats.sort {
     guard let first = $0.someBool, let second = $1.someBool else { return false }
     return first && !second
}
```

2. check nil

> ```
> >  chats.sort {
> >              guard let first = $0.someBool, let second = $1.someBool else { return false }
> >              return true
> >         }
> ```